# Creating URL for pagination, ordering and filters - ZF

Tags: php, zend-framework, url, url-rewriting, zend-router

I everyone who's reading this,

I was on the Internet 5 minutes ago and I found a URL that was pretty nice:

```
www.exemple.com/blog/rating.asc/2
```

Which is related to:

```
blog => controller/action/module or anything
rating => ordered by
asc => order of list
2 => current page
```

I would like to know how I can create similar URL using the `Zend_Controller_Router_Route` class of Zend Framework.

For my website, it would be like:

```
www.exemple.com/portfolio/date.asc/2
```

or

```
www.exemple.com/blog/author.desc/ (page optional, default 1)
```

and

```
www.exemple.com/blog/ (default order: date.asc, page: 1)
```

**NOTE:** I'm not friendly with Regex, so I would like to forbid that or if someone who the exact expression, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I'm not sure if you are use ini for configuration but here is how I'd do it if I had a:

```
module     => blog
controller => article
action     => list
// Parameter to get from the request in the controller
// Note that those are the defaults in case you don't provide any parameters in the url
sortBy => author
order  => asc
page   => 1
```

in the ini file:

```
; /www.exemple.com/blog/articles/author/desc/2
resources.router.routes.whateverroutname.route = /blog/articles/:sortBy/:order/:page
resources.router.routes.whateverroutname.defaults.module = blog
resources.router.routes.whateverroutname.defaults.controller = article
resources.router.routes.whateverroutname.defaults.action = list
resources.router.routes.whateverroutname.defaults.sortBy = author
resources.router.routes.whateverroutname.defaults.order = asc
resources.router.routes.whateverroutname.defaults.page = 1
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Well, this is pretty good except that the sorting and the order are not divided by a `/` but by a `.`.

Comment: The Zend Router separates the parameters based on a route match. The matching-parameter separator is "/". May be you'll have to write your own writer that will consider "." as a parameter separator and covert routs like this /blog/articles/:sortBy.:order/:page. Bear in mind thought, that the "." sign is used to sometimes separate words in CEO. Therefore your link might be misinterpreted by some of the search engines.